# Is it useful to create pointer(s) on the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it useful to create a pointer or an array of pointers on the heap ? if so when and why would I need to do so ?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Box { /*  things... */ };

int main(void){

    // Single pointer on the heap
    Box** pBox = new Box*(nullptr);
    *pBox = new Box();

    // Array of pointers on the heap
    Box** pBoxes = new Box*[3]{};
    pBoxes[0] = new Box();
    pBoxes[1] = new Box();
    pBoxes[2] = new Box();

    // Delete pointers...

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Just to make my question more clear ... I know dealing with raw pointers is not the best practice ... I just want to fully understand pointers and their uses as they are important part of c++ hence my question is (is it useful...).

Comment: If you're joining a Gentlemen's Java Club, you may be required to write code like this if you want to avoid getting hazed.

Comment: @KerrekSB, and the logical continuation is - but this would be the only reason to do this.

Comment: If an object has pointer members, and you create the object on the heap, you automatically have pointers on the heap....

Comment: For the second case, you usually want to use std::array or std::vector.

Comment: call by reference vs call by value?!

Comment: Yes, it is useful :)

Comment: Remember:  to access the target of a pointer, the pointer must be dereferenced.  The usually method for allocating on a heap returns a pointer.  So now you have a pointer to a pointer to a Box.  In order to access the Box, you have to deference the pointer to the pointer, then dereference again.  A lot of extra work, when you can declare the variable locally.

Comment: There are two cases for using a pointer (using new/delete):

 - The object created is huge.
 - The object crated is polymorphic.

Both can be avoided by using a std::unique_ptr or std:shared_ptr. Hence you can use a std::vector holding one of these pointers to represent your array. However, old code is not aware of these pointer types and you might have to use that old style of manual managing the lifetime of an object.

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning behind allocating any memory space on the heap or on the stack is not related to the type of variables allocated, it's related to how it's allocated and how it's meant to be used.

In any case, nowadays you should usually avoid `new` statements and use "managed" pointers, particularly the `std::xxx` variants.

Comment: I know smart pointers ... but as pointers are very important part of c++ ... I just want to fully understand them even if its better to avoid using raw pointers

Comment: Another reason is the lifetime of the variable.  A variable declared in dynamic memory can live past the execution of a function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's mostly what I meant by "*how it's meant to be used*".

Answer (score 2):

From what i read, the heap has slower access speed than the stack so, I don't think that it is very useful to do what you are talking about.
Maybe this will help you trought your research: http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Comment: To be clear, the *allocation* of a variable from the heap (dynamic memory), is slower than allocating from the stack.  The access speed should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

As another answer mentioned, usually actual access to the heap is slower than access to the stack, however access speed generally isn't the reason for creating and dealing with pointers.

The typical use case for pointers is to avoid copying data. When you're dealing with large objects and passing them between many functions, it is considered "better" to pass by reference rather than by value.

If you use the object from the stack (unless you pass it as a reference, but there are limitations when doing this) it makes a copy of the whole thing for the called method. When passing a pointer to a method, it is only copying an address.

See if [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/) helps you understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be reasons to have pointers on the heap. A factory function that keeps track of every object it creates might store them in a vector, for example:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Box>> BoxFactory::allBoxes;

Box* BoxFactory::makeBox()
{
    allBoxes.emplace_back(make_unique<Box>());
    return allBoxes.back().get();
}
```

Note: some people have suggested that this is not double-indirection. It is:

```
// Accesses some_box_member of the first Box.
allBoxes.data()->get()->some_box_member
```

Just as with the OP's example, you have two pointers in play, not just one. The vector contains pointers which have been allocated on the heap, and those pointers contain another pointer that points to the Box object.

Comment: This is allocating a `Box`, not a `Box*`.

Comment: @Barry `unique_ptr` is allocating a `Box`. The vector is allocating pointers (wrapped in `unique_ptr` here.) So the vector contains pointers on the heap, and those pointers point to Boxes.

Comment: The OP's concept is a pointer to a pointer; double indirection.  Possible, not very efficient.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The OP has an array of pointers on the heap. A `vector<unique_ptr<Box>>` is in the end an array of pointers on the heap :-) (You can imagine it as a `vector<Box*>`, but I try not to give code examples anymore that encourage manual memory management.)